# (Beautiful) alternative to OS X Mail application for other OSes

Tags: windows, linux, osx, email

I've heard that Mozilla Thunderbird is the winner within cross-platform mail clients, and happily used it before. But now I miss the look and feel of native OS X Mail application so much. Especially these "fat" items in message list — they allow the message list to take less horizontal space and then the message content is perfectly fitting on the right hand side.
Maybe there are ways to "style" the Thunderbird to (almost) the same look?
When I just select "vertical" layout, it doesn't help much — items in message list are still single-line, so the list must still be wide or it won't show useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a few email clients lately and, unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be anything out there that is both functional and attractive out of the box.

On Linux, I've recently had a go with **Thunderbird**, **KMail**, **Evolution** and **Geary**.  Of these, Thunderbird and KMail are the only ones that actually provide a remotely nice user experience and also have enough features for practical use.  On Windows, you of course have the **Outlook** option as well and I think this is better in every way than the aforementioned open source alternatives.

My suggestion therefore would be to stick with Mozilla Thunderbird but explore the [themes](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/themes/) available to install as add-ons.  I'd be surprised if there isn't one that is actually based on Mac OSX.

Comment: I didn't try installing them yet, but from what I can see on the website I'm suspecting that they are all just a bunch of graphical resources and nothing more — that means, they can't really change layout of UI elements...